Show that $E\left(x_\alpha^{\text {sym }}\right)=0$
I am doing this recommended exercise in the course Unsupervised Learning and I would greatly appreciate some input about whether my solution seems correct or not? I do not have so much theory on this subject and hence I ask you here. Specifically, is it correct for me to assume that

$\lambda_1^{\text{sym}} = 0$ corresponds to the constant eigenvector (the eigenvalue associated with the trivial eigenvalue) and for $\alpha > 1$, the eigenvectors $v_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}}$ are orthogonal to the constant eigenvector, meaning they have zero mean.

Here is the full question and solution:
Consider graphs with a single connected component, the CTD embedding coordinates for $L_{\text {sym }}$ is $x_{\alpha i}^{\text {sym }}=v_{\alpha i}^{\text {sym }} \sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{vol}(\mathrm{V})}{\lambda_\alpha^{\text {sym }} d_i}}$ as discussed in the class. Show that $E\left(x_\alpha^{\text {sym }}\right)=0$ for $\alpha>1$ with the weight of each data point given by $P(i)=d_i / \operatorname{vol}(V)$.
We start by solving (a). The expectation is computed using the weighted probability, where the weight of each data point is given by:
$$
P(i) = \frac{d_i}{\mathrm{vol}(V)}.
$$
This can be expressed as:
$$
E\left(x_\alpha^{\text{sym}}\right) = \sum_{i} P(i) x_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}} = \sum_{i} \frac{d_i}{\mathrm{vol}(V)} x_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}}.
$$
Substituting the expression for $x_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}}$:
\begin{align*}
E\left(x_\alpha^{\text{sym}}\right) &= \sum_{i} \frac{d_i}{\mathrm{vol}(V)} v_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}} \sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{vol}(V)}{\lambda_\alpha^{\text{sym}} d_i}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\mathrm{vol}(V)}}{\mathrm{vol}(V) \sqrt{\lambda_\alpha^{\text{sym}}}} \sum_{i} v_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}} \cdot \sqrt{d_i}.
\end{align*}
The eigenvalues $v_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}}$ correspond to the eigenvectors of the Laplacian matrix associated with the graph. For a connected component of the graph, the eigenvalues have the following properties: $\lambda_1^{\text{sym}} = 0$ corresponds to the constant eigenvector (the eigenvalue associated with the trivial eigenvalue) and for $\alpha > 1$, the eigenvectors $v_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}}$ are orthogonal to the constant eigenvector, meaning they have zero mean. Mathematically, this can be expressed as:
$$
\sum_{i} v_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}} = 0 \quad \text{for} \quad \alpha > 1.
$$
Thus, the term $\sum_{i} v_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}} \cdot \sqrt{d_i}$ contributes nothing to the expected value because the sum of $v_{\alpha i}^{\text{sym}}$ across the nodes is zero:
$$
E\left(x_\alpha^{\text{sym}}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{\mathrm{vol}(V)}}{\mathrm{vol}(V) \sqrt{\lambda_\alpha^{\text{sym}}}} \cdot 0 = 0.
$$
Thanks in advance!
